# SQL Left Join 2 Tables where Condition

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have 2 tables: AllClients & AllPolicies.  I'm trying to find Client Records where there are no "active policies".  An active policy is a policy where the effective date is before today and the expiration date is after today.  Here is the sql I've come up with but it won't execute:

```
SELECT ac.LookupCode
  FROM AllClients ac
  LEFT JOIN AllPolicies ap 
    ON ap.LookupCode = ac.LookupCode
   AND ap.EffectiveDate  < '2014-06-24'
   AND ap.ExpirationDate > '2014-06-24'
```

I'm using mySQL and I'm getting some weird "unknown table status: TABLE_TYPE" errors.  I'm fairly confident my SQL statement is junk ;)  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT LookupCode
FROM AllClients
where LookupCode not in 
    (select LookupCode 
    from AllPolicies
    where EffectiveDate < '2014-06-24' and ExpirationDate > '2014-06-24')
```

Comment: This works, but it is incredibly slow.  Any suggestions on how to speed it up?

Comment: Try creating an index(seperate one) on column Lookupcode in both table     CREATE INDEX <<index_name>> ON <<column name with type and size>>

Comment: I did index those columns in both tables and I'm still having issues.  Any other performance enhancing ideas?

Answer (score -1):

This might help. You haven't expounded much on your mySQL errors, and they might have something to do with your table structures or server setup.

```
SELECT
 ac.LookupCode
FROM
 AllClients ac
 LEFT JOIN AllPolicies ap ON ap.LookupCode = ac.LookupCode
  AND ap.EffectiveDate < @Today
  AND ap.ExpirationDate > @Today
WHERE
 ap.LookupCode IS NULL --This means do not get records that have active policies
```

Comment: I get the same error messages on this.  The exact error message is: "unknown table status: TABLE_TYPE".  I'd love to expound, but that is all that is shown in the error message.  The query executes for a long time before that error is thrown.  Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: This is also giving me accounts that have active policies, not accounts with inactive policies.  I believe the error message is related to phpmyadmin so that is somewhat irrelevant.

Answer (score -1):

```
> SELECT AllClients.LookupCode FROM AllClients Left Join AllPolicies on
> AllPolicies.LookupCode = AllClients.LookupCode
>      and date(AllPolicies.EffectiveDate) < date '2014-06-24'
>      and date(AllPolicies.ExpirationDate) > date '2014-06-24';
```

Comment: This is giving me accounts that have active policies, not accounts without active policies.

Answer (score -1):

Troubleshoot as follows.  Start with this:

```
select ac.*
from AllClients ac
where 1 = 2
```

If it runs successfully, advance to this

```
select ac.LookUpCode
from AllClients ac
where 1 = 2
```

Then this:

```
select ac.LookUpCode
from AllClients ac left AllPolicies ap on 1 = 2
where 1 = 2
```

Keep going, adding one bit at a time.  Once you get an error, you'll know what caused it.

Comment: Thanks, but I think the error is related to phpmyadmin and a display issue.